# Change Attribut when Specific Option is Selected in Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

So there is my following code :
index.html

```
<img id="crypto-pic" src="./assets/img/cryptos/btc.png" alt="crypto" height="15" width="15">

     <select id="input-crypto" class="form-control">
        <option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="ethereum">Ethereum</option>
...
...
...
      </select>
```

script.js :

```
if($("#input-crypto option:selected").text() == bitcoin){
  $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', './assets/img/cryptos/btc.png');
};

if($("#input-crypto option:selected").text() == ethereum){
  $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', './assets/img/cryptos/eth.png');
};
```

The fact is that when Ethereum is selected in the list, the image don't change to eth.png.
Can you help me please, thanks.

Comment: Two code smells around the `bitcoin` and `ethereum` are not in single or double quotes to signify that they are strings.  Do you have variables of the same name that have those strings as their values?  Otherwise that is a syntax error.

Comment: Even with quotes, it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an onChange event, and a switch statement for less code and more flexibility

```
$("#input-crypto").on("change", function(){
    var imgSrc;
    switch($(this).val()) {
      case "ethereum":
          imgSrc = './assets/img/cryptos/eth.png';
        break;
      case "anotherOption1":
          imgSrc = './assets/img/cryptos/xxx.png';
        break;
      case "anotherOption2":
          imgSrc = './assets/img/cryptos/xxx.png';
        break;
      default:
          imgSrc = './assets/img/cryptos/btc.png';
    }
    $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: default (e.g. Bitcoin) should always be last

Comment: I've edited the answer to show additional options in the switch. Remember to include `break` after each option too, otherwise `default` will override the previous options

Answer (score 1):

You have missed single or double quotes around `bitcoin` and `ethereum`. Also if you are running the scripts without any function call or listener, it wont work.

For your better understanding, track the change of selection using `.change()` function and then check the latest selected value.

```
$("#input-crypto").change(function(){
  if($("#input-crypto").val() == "bitcoin"){
    $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', './assets/img/cryptos/btc.png');
  };

  if($("#input-crypto").val() == "ethereum"){
    $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', './assets/img/cryptos/eth.png');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.on()` function to achieve it.

```
    $('#input-crypto').on('change', function () {
        var selectedOption = $(this).val();

        if (selectedOption == "bitcoin") {
            $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', './Content/img/cryptos/btc.png');
        }

        if (selectedOption == "ethereum") {
            $('#crypto-pic').attr('src', './assets/img/cryptos/eth.png');
        }
    });
```